# Engine starts strong, but slowly dies out

Tags: engine, mercury, grand-marquis

Mercury Grand Marquis 86. When I crank it it starts strong, it slowly dies out. New solenoid and starter need help. Disconnected the engine from tranny tried everything I just need some fresh thoughts anything will help

Comment: Have you checked all the cables including the ground cables between battery and body and body and engine?

Comment: Thank for reply I have and also just to make sure I cleaned it up to ensure it has good connection

Comment: Also forgot to add I can turn the crank manually 360 with no problem

Comment: This sounds like a fuel issue. Which engine is your Grand Marquis running? The 5.0 is fuel injected and has an electric fuel pump. If the pump isn't keeping up, it would give you the basic issue you are talking about. To see if it's keeping up, you'll need to put a fuel pressure gauge on the fuel rail to see how the fuel pressure is behaving. If it tapers off right after starting, it could be the in tank fuel strainer, the fuel pump, or the fuel filter (or a combination of any of the three). If this is the 5.8L engine, it could be the manual fuel pump, but not quite sure.

Comment: It is a 5.0 and the fuel pump inside the engine correct?

Comment: @Jonee140 - If it's a 5.0, the fuel pump is inside the fuel tank. Did I read your question correctly? Does it actually start, run, then die? Or are you saying the starter itself starts out strong, then dies off? Completely different symptoms. Please correct me if I misread your question!

Comment: It does not turn over, the starter is brand new and is starts off strong then slowly dies out